# Three tabs having their own individual scroll views

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-scrollview

I am trying to make an interface in which there are three tabs inside a tabhost and which will have their own individual scroll views. 
The content placeholder of individual tabs has to be scrollable but from below the **tab button** itself (so that user can change from tab#1 to tab#2 without scrolling all the way up by just clicking in the tab's button.)
This is kind of a layout in which scroll views are inside the content placeholder of the tab(s) and **not** a tab inside a scroll view.
So far I have come up with this:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".Ques2" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:gravity="bottom" />

        <FrameLayout
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/tabview1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ScrollView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/scrollViewTab1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fillViewport="true" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1_monthly_vOlslab_R1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/monthly_vOlslab_R1"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/cb1R1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_monthly_vOlslab_R1"
                            android:text="@string/cb1R1" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/cb2R1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/cb1R1"
                            android:text="@string/cb2R1" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/cb3R1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/cb2R1"
                            android:text="@string/cb3R1" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/cb4R1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/cb3R1"
                            android:text="@string/cb4R1" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/cb5R1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/cb4R1"
                            android:text="@string/cb5R1" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/cb6R1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/cb5R1"
                            android:text="@string/cb6R1" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/cb7R1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/cb6R1"
                            android:text="@string/cb7R1" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/cb8R1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/cb7R1"
                            android:text="@string/cb8R1" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/viewTab1Q1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="2dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/cb8R1"
                            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                            android:paddingTop="2dp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/tabview2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="tabview2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/tabview3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="tabview3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not do this, `TabHost` is old and horrible. Use `Fragments` and a `ViewPager` [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

There is a plethora of tutorials and examples of how to do this. The best being from @commonsguy [Fragments with ViewPager](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments)

Comment: thanks for replying. But isn't `Fragments` incompatible with Android 2.x OR 3.x and up? **Update** I am targeting 2.3.x and up :|

Comment: You can use the compatibility library (http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) to make Fragments work with your application.

Comment: Thanks guys :) will try and post back my results here (will mark it as the answer too if I make it through)

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins Hi, The example given by commonsguy uses an external library (see import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;) and  I really don't want to use another library. Is there a simple way of doing the same? I can certainly get my hands dirty with the tabhosts etc. :|

Comment: @quantumstates you dont need to use actionbar sherlock, but you should really be using Android Support Library Meaning, just extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `SherlockFragmentActivity`

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins nvm I have implemented the 3 tabs using tab hosts and I am calling 3 different activity in each tab. I can now have more distributed/moduled code :D Anyways thanks for replying and trying to help me out :) though I am marking yours as the Answer so that others should follow the more advanced/customizable approach.